# Conditional formatting - Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Tags: excel

I hope you are all well.

I have a range of cells A1:A8. They all have either Passed or Failed in them.
What I have been doing is to use conditional formatting and create two rules:

- The first one: Highlight in green cells that contain "Passed"
- The second one: Highlight in red cells that contain "Failed"

Is there any way I only have to use one formula? Perhaps "AND"?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two cell formatting on one rule.
Perhaps you can mark the range green or red with normal formatting and only apply one rule.
So for example make all cells red with normal formatting. Then apply conditional formatting for only the first rule. So if it is Passed, it will be green otherwise always red.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks